# Database is not displaying the details I enter despite there being no error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So I am creating a security checklist through Django. First, the user has to fill out basic details namely property name, manager name and inspected. After filling in the above-mentioned fields, the user then clicks a button which takes him to a checklist. After filling out the checklist, the user is then taken to another form where they have to fill out security details like safe? department and target correction date. After filling it out, the user is redirected to a thank you page.
Everything seems to work fine but the data I enter doesn't get entered in the database.
P.S:- I'm still learning Django and hence I haven't added any advanced interactions for the checklist

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class BasicDetails(models.Model):
    property_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    inspected_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.property_name


class SafetyDetails(models.Model):
    basic_details = models.OneToOneField(BasicDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    safe = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    target_correction_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.basic_details.property_name
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import BasicDetails, SafetyDetails

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        property_name = request.POST['property_name']
        manager_name = request.POST['manager_name']
        inspected_by = request.POST['inspected_by']
        print(property_name, manager_name, inspected_by)

        basic_details = BasicDetails()
        basic_details.property_name = property_name
        basic_details.manager_name = manager_name
        basic_details.inspected_by = inspected_by
        try:
            basic_details.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error saving basic details: {str(e)}")

        return redirect('checklist')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def secondpart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        safe = request.POST['safe']
        Department = request.POST['Department']
        target_correction_date = request.POST['target_correction_date']
        print(safe, Department, target_correction_date)

        basic_details = BasicDetails.objects.latest('id')

        safety_details = SafetyDetails()
        safety_details.basic_details = basic_details
        safety_details.safe = safe
        safety_details.Department = Department
        safety_details.target_correction_date = target_correction_date
        try:
            safety_details.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error saving safety details: {str(e)}")

        return redirect('thankyou')

    return render(request, 'secondpart.html')

def thankyou(request):
    return render(request, 'thankyou.html')

def checklist(request):
    return render(request, 'checklist.html')
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <form method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Security Checklist Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Property Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="property_name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Manager Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="manager_name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Inspected By:</label>
            <input type="text" name="inspected_by" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'checklist' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Go to Checklist</a>
        
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`checklist.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Home Page</title> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            
            <thead>
                <th>Security Area</th>
                <th>Checklist Item</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            </div>
            <tr>
                <td>Physical</td>
                <td><p>Secure Physical Access</p> <br>
                <p>Install Surveillance Devices</p><br>
                <p>Implement Firewalls<p></td>
                <td><div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                      
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                          
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                              
                    </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="enter comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Network</td>
                <td><p>Regulary scan network for vulneribilities</p> <br>
                <p>Enable encryption for network traffic</p><br>
                </td>
                <td><div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                      
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                          
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="enter comments"></textarea>
                    
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>System & Application</td>
                <td><p>Multi-factor Authentication</p> <br>
                <p>Strong Passwords</p><br>
                <p>Utilize anti-virus and other malware detection tech<p></td>
                <td><div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                      
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                          
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                              
                    </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="enter comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td>Secure Coding Practise</td>
                <td><p>Train developers about scp</p> <br>
                <p>Use more error handling mechanism</p><br>
                <p>Perform code review<p></td>
                <td><div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                      
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                          
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                              
                    </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="enter comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td>Employee</td>
                <td><p>Conduct background checks from 3rd party</p> <br>
                <p>Monitor and manage employee access</p><br>
                <p>Provide Security Awareness Training<p></td>
                <td><div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                      
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                          
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                              
                    </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="enter comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td>Third-Party</td>
                <td><p>Evaluate security practises of vendors</p> <br>
                <p>Regularly monitor and update vendor access permissions</p><br>
                <p>Implement security clause and requirements<p></td>
                <td><div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                      
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                          
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                              
                    </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="enter comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td>Compliance & Legal</td>
                <td><p>Understand and comply with safety regulations</p> <br>
                <p>Maintain software license compliance</p><br>
                <p>Document security policies,procedures and incidents<p></td>
                <td><div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                      
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                          
                    </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >
                              
                    </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="enter comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
        <a href="{% url 'secondpart' %}"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

`secondpart.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Home Page</title> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
       
    
            
            <div class="container">
                <form method="post">

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Safe?:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="safe" class="form-control" placeholder="Remember to fill form before entering" required title="Please fill the form before entering here">
                        

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Department:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Department" class="form-control" required  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Target Correction Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="target_correction_date" class="form-control" required >
                        </div>
                    <a href="{% url 'thankyou' %}" class="btn btn-primary" required>Submit</a>
                    
                </form>
                
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There few things you need to correct

`index.html`

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Security Checklist Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Property Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="property_name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Manager Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="manager_name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Inspected By:</label>
            <input type="text" name="inspected_by" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go to Checklist</button>
        
    </form>
```

above I have to change the code line `<a href="{% url 'checklist' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Go to Checklist</a>` into a button in order to correctly submit the form.

And also you want to update your code in the `secondpart.html` `form` into `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>`

can you provide more information about the `checklist.html` like what your try to do?

Comment: The content in index.html takes you to the checklist. The checklist is something you may or may not fill dependimg on your interest. Below the checklist is a submit button which will take you to the contents in seconfpart.html and after filling out that, you are redirected to a thank you page

Comment: Ok if you update your code as I mention earlier you will able to submit your form and save data into the database but in the `checklist.html` that not the case the code you provided to the `checklist.html` not contain any form for data submission and there are not data pass into the template so I think you first implement the logic either submit data into the database or passing data from the view to the `checklist.html`.

Comment: I followed your advice and it works now. Turns out I forgot to use the button tag